# Reshaping dataset

Tags: r

I am just wondering if you could guide me to the right direction about how can I reshape a dataset based on a specific criteria to arrange by hours, for example, I have the follwing example dataset:
[image: Dataframe]

I am trying to reshape the dataset to look like this:

[image]

how can I proceed with this reshaping please? Many Thanks.

```
My sample data:

data = structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Jan-97", class = "factor"), day = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), hour = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Value = c(65L, 29L, 
31L, 42L, 42L, 52L, 61L, 57L, 55L, 52L, 57L, 46L)), .Names = c("date", 
"day", "hour", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses the `reshape2` package. I am sure it can be done with the `reshape` function, but I am not as facile with that.

```
library("reshape2")
dcast(data, date+day~hour, value.var="Value")
```

which gives

```
> dcast(data, date+day~hour, value.var="Value")
    date day  1  2  3  4
1 Jan-97   1 65 29 31 42
2 Jan-97   2 42 52 61 57
3 Jan-97   3 55 52 57 46
```

If you don't like the names from that, you can change them afterwards.

```
widedata <- dcast(data, date+day~hour, value.var="Value")
names(widedata)[-(1:2)] <- paste0("hour",names(widedata[-(1:2)]))
```

so `widedata` is:

```
> widedata
    date day hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4
1 Jan-97   1    65    29    31    42
2 Jan-97   2    42    52    61    57
3 Jan-97   3    55    52    57    46
```

Comment: +1 I was still typing.  the `reshape` package and `cast` will do the same thing.  `cast(data, date+day~hour, value='Value')`

Comment: Thanks Brian and Justin, thats exatly what I was looking for to understand how to reshape generally. thanks again, regards,#

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using `reshape`

```
reshape(data, idvar=c('date','day'), direction='wide', timevar='hour')
```

Comment: thanks Smu for your answer, the first one is more appropriate to what I am looking for, but thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to do it in base:

```
reshape(data, timevar = c("hour"), v.names = c("Value"),  
    idvar = c("date", "day"), direction = "wide")
```

EDIT:  Like Brian used if want to retain the names use:

```
names(DF)[-c(1:2)] <- paste0("hour", 1:4)
rownames(DF)<- 1:nrow(DF)
DF
```

Yielding:

```
    date day hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4
1 Jan-97   1    65    29    31    42
2 Jan-97   2    42    52    61    57
3 Jan-97   3    55    52    57    46
```

Answer (score 1):

An update using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(hour=paste0('hour', hour)) %>% spread(hour, Value)
#    date day hour1 hour2 hour3 hour4
#1 Jan-97   1    65    29    31    42
#2 Jan-97   2    42    52    61    57
#3 Jan-97   3    55    52    57    46
```

Comment: In case to change the column names, `library(dplyr); data %>% mutate(hour=paste0('hour', hour)) %>% spread(hour, Value))` or just use `spread(data, hour,Value) %>% setNames(., c(names(.)[1:2], paste0('hour', names(.)[3:6])))`

Comment: @akrun Looks much better. I'm going to go through other examples and practice wide and long reshapes.