# Can dcast be used without an aggregate function?

Tags: r, reshape2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This R reshaping should be simple, but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829995/this-r-reshaping-should-be-simple-but)

`dcast` from `reshape2` works without a formula where there are no duplicates. Take these example data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), cat = c("SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SV", "SV", "SV"), val = c(220L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 
225L, 2206L)), .Names = c("id", "cat", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I'd like to `dcast` these data and just have the values tabulated, without applying any function to the `value.var` including the default `length`.

In this case, it works fine.

```
> dcast(df, id~cat, value.var="val")
  id  SS   SV
1  A 220  224
2  B 222  225
3  C 223 2206
```

But when there are duplicate variables, the `fun` defaults to `length`. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C"), cat = c("SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SV", "SV", "SV", "SV"), val = c(220L, 222L, 223L, 
224L, 225L, 220L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "cat", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

> dcast(df2, id~cat, value.var="val")
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  id SS SV
1  A  1  1
2  B  1  1
3  C  1  2
```

Ideally what I'm looking for is to add a `fun = NA`, as in don't try to aggregate the `value.var`. The result I'd like when dcasting df2:

```
 id  SS  SV
1  A 220 224
2  B 222 225
3  C 223 220
4. C NA  1
```

Comment: What would you like it to do when there is duplication?

Comment: Just add that in as another row with a `NA` for any missing values.

Comment: @Dason Is it kosher to answer my own question now that I figured out a solution? Or should I just delete the q?

Comment: It's definitely kosher.  It's always nice seeing the different ways the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it directly but we can add in an additional column which will help us out

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C"), cat = c("SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SV", "SV", "SV", "SV"), val = c(220L, 222L, 223L, 
224L, 225L, 220L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "cat", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
# Add a variable for how many times the id*cat combination has occured
tmp <- ddply(df2, .(id, cat), transform, newid = paste(id, seq_along(cat)))
# Aggregate using this newid and toss in the id so we don't lose it
out <- dcast(tmp, id + newid ~ cat, value.var = "val")
# Remove newid if we want
out <- out[,-which(colnames(out) == "newid")]
> out
#  id  SS  SV
#1  A 220 224
#2  B 222 225
#3  C 223 220
#4  C  NA   1
```

Comment: Thanks, I arrived at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out the same solution while Dason was answering mine.

I realized that `dcast` simply does not know how to deal with duplicates. The way I figured out how to trick it was by adding another unique identifer so it doesn't get confused by duplicates.

In this example:

```
df <- ddply(df2, .(cat), function(x){ x$id2 = 1:nrow(x); x})
>  dcast(df, id+id2~cat, value.var="val")[,-2]
  id  SS  SV
1  A 220 224
2  B 222 225
3  C 223 220
4  C  NA   1
```

Comment: that was so helpful for a similar case for me. Thank you :)

Comment: You saved my day!!