# Error: Can't cast <list_of<character>> to <character> after using new pivot_wider() function in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a large long dataset of pathology results. Each patient has a unique identifier (in this case `row_id`. For each patient they have had samples taken on a particular date (`sample_date`). The range of tests that they have had is very varied and with a heterogeneous output (some with character strings, and some numeric). Also, not every patient has had every test performed at each `sample_date`, so there should be quite a few NAs.

The name of the test performed is in the `test_name` column, and the result is in the `result` column.
I would like to make this into a wide dataset, spreading the `result` column using the `test_name` as the column headers, but keeping the identifiers as both  `row_id` and `sample_date`.

The new `pivot_wider()` function in tidyr seems to be perfect for my needs, and when I run it, it gives me the type of data frame I need (i.e., rows are still identified by `row_id` and sample_date but now there are columns for each test_name and results therein.

Here is a small sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(row_id = 1:81, sample_date = structure(c(16444, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
16444, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 
16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 
16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16448, 
16448, 16448, 16448, 16448, 16448, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442), class = "Date"), 
    test_name = c("Epidemic Typhus Group IgG Abs", "Epidemic Typhus Group IgM Abs", 
    "Spotted Fever Group IgG Abs", "Spotted Fever Group IgM Abs", 
    "Albumin", "Alkaline phosphatase", "Alanine transaminase", 
    "Basophils", "Bilirubin (total)", "Creatinine", "C-reactive protein", 
    "Eosinophils", "Estimated GFR", "Haemoglobin (g/L)", "HCT", 
    "Potassium", "Lymphocytes", "MCHC (g/L)", "MCH", "MCV", "Monocytes", 
    "MPV", "Sodium", "Neutrophils", "Platelet count", "Red cell count", 
    "RDW", "Urea", "White cell count", "Albumin", "Alkaline phosphatase", 
    "Alanine transaminase", "Basophils", "Bilirubin (total)", 
    "Creatinine", "C-reactive protein", "Eosinophils", "Estimated GFR", 
    "Haemoglobin (g/L)", "HCT", "Potassium", "Lymphocytes", "MCHC (g/L)", 
    "MCH", "MCV", "Monocytes", "MPV", "Sodium", "Neutrophils", 
    "Platelet count", "Red cell count", "RDW", "Urea", "White cell count", 
    "Creatinine", "C-reactive protein", "Estimated GFR", "Potassium", 
    "Sodium", "Urea", "Albumin", "Alkaline phosphatase", "Alanine transaminase", 
    "APTT Ratio", "APTT", "Basophils", "Bilirubin (total)", "Creatinine", 
    "C-reactive protein", "Eosinophils", "Fibrinogen", "Estimated GFR", 
    "Haemoglobin (g/L)", "HCT", "INR", "Potassium", "Lymphocytes", 
    "MCHC (g/L)", "MCH", "MCV", "Monocytes"), result = c("Not detected", 
    "Not detected", "Not detected", "Not detected", "47", "84", 
    "29", "0.3%  0.03", "12", "98", "3.3", "1.7%  0.15", "77\r\nUnits: mL/min/1.73sqm\r\nMultiply eGFR by 1.21 for people of African\r\nCaribbean origin. Interpret with regard to UK CKD\r\nguidelines: www.renal.org/information-resources\r\nUse with caution for adjusting drug dosages -\r\ncontact clinical pharmacist for advice.", 
    "156", "0.435", "3.8", "25.7%  2.31", "359", "30.4", "84.6", 
    "7.1%  0.64", "10.1", "140", "65.2%  5.86", "240", "5.14", 
    "12.4", "3.9", "8.99", "45", "53", "41", "0.3%  0.03", "10", 
    "59", "2.0", "2.8%  0.32", ">90\r\nUnits: mL/min/1.73sqm\r\nMultiply eGFR by 1.21 for people of African\r\nCaribbean origin. Interpret with regard to UK CKD\r\nguidelines: www.renal.org/information-resources\r\nUse with caution for adjusting drug dosages -\r\ncontact clinical pharmacist for advice.", 
    "126", "0.398", "4.5", "28.7%  3.30", "317", "25.7", "81.2", 
    "5.7%  0.65", "10.8", "143", "62.5%  7.18", "411", "4.90", 
    "14.7", "3.5", "11.49", "59", "76.2", ">90\r\nUnits: mL/min/1.73sqm\r\nMultiply eGFR by 1.21 for people of African\r\nCaribbean origin. Interpret with regard to UK CKD\r\nguidelines: www.renal.org/information-resources\r\nUse with caution for adjusting drug dosages -\r\ncontact clinical pharmacist for advice.", 
    "4.2", "139", "3.4", "46", "47", "40", "1.3", "39", "0.4%  0.01", 
    "8", "74", "7.0", "0.4%  0.01", "2.50", ">90\r\nUnits: mL/min/1.73sqm\r\nMultiply eGFR by 1.21 for people of African\r\nCaribbean origin. Interpret with regard to UK CKD\r\nguidelines: www.renal.org/information-resources\r\nUse with caution for adjusting drug dosages -\r\ncontact clinical pharmacist for advice.", 
    "146", "0.441", "0.96", "4.3", "43.2%  1.14", "331", "29.1", 
    "87.8", "6.8%  0.18")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-81L))
```

This is the `pivot_wider()` code I have used (having called the dataset above `path_results`:

```
library(tidyr)

path_results_wide <- path_results %>%
  select(row_id, sample_date, test_name, result)%>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(row_id,
                sample_date), 
    names_from = test_name, 
    values_from = result
  )
```

Some columns should be numerical, and some should be character strings, but `pivot_wider()` has parsed them all as lists of characters and when I try and change them to numerical, I get the following error:

```
path_results_wide$Albumin <- as.numeric(path_results_wide$Albumin)
```

> Error: Can't cast <list_of<character>> to <double>

Any suggestions for what I can do to fix this would be very welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old answer:

Not sure about pivot_wider, but if I undestood correctly, I think this might be what you want, using reshape2. There are several NA values since each row is a patient and a date, on which a specific test was performed.

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(path_results, row_id + sample_date ~ test_name)
```

New answer:

Reading about the dcast function in another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831524/can-dcast-be-used-without-an-aggregate-function), I realized we needed to add another id column to uniquely identify each separate row. I then came across the following while reading about the spread function in dplyr:

```
path_results_wide <- path_results %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    spread(test_name, result)
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely looks like what I would need, and certainly when I try it on the sample of data that I posted above, it works fine. When I try it on my full dataset (~500 000 rows that result in approx. 1000 different columns from the test_names, the columns have all been parsed as integers (presumably relating to the number of times a result exists in that specific cell?).  Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Do you mean the column names have been parsed as integers? Or the values in the columns? Maybe check if some of the columns in your full dataset are factor types?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think so. The columns in the full dataset are all character, apart from sample_date. The issue seems to be when cast can't variables do not identify a single observation for each output cell

Comment: ie. when there are multiple measurements (result) for a given test (test_name) for a patient (row_id) on the same date (sample_date). I think when it can't identify a single observation for each output cell, it invokes fun.aggregate and returns a summary statistic instead of the actual result. Ideally, I would have dcast create an additional row for the additional values. Not sure how best to overcome this. I've tried various permutations of fun.aggregate but without success.