# Reshape data frame with no idvar - R

Tags: r, reshape

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
name <- rep(LETTERS[seq(from=1, to =2)], each=3)
MeasA <- c(1:6)
MeasB <- c(7:12)

df <- data.frame(name, MeasA, MeasB)
```

And I want to reshape into a format which has no idvar like this:

```
MeasA_A MeasB_A MeasB_B MeasB_B
 1        7        4      10
 2        8        5      11
 3        9        6      12
```

I have been reading about reshape and melt:

[Reshaping data frame with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829995/reshaping-data-frame-with-duplicates)

http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html

But with those functions I need to specify an idvar. Ive tried:

```
tt <- reshape(df, timevar = "name", direction="wide")
```

and

```
tt <- dcast(df, ~name)
```

But they clearly dont work. Perhaps I need to use split ([Split data.frame based on levels of a factor into new data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames)) then a reshape?

Comment: Do you want to get the `mean` value after dcast?  Try `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, ind:=LETTERS[1:.N], name]; dcast(df, name~ind, value.var=c('MeasA', 'MeasB'), sep="_", mean)`

Comment: I dont need the mean values. Just columns with the Measurement (MeasA or MeasB) concatenated with name (and corresponding data under each). I will try and make my desired output more friendly.

Comment: It is better to show a small example data and then the expected output will be easy to show.

Comment: exactly, you will need to aggregate your data in some ways ... by mean or sum or maximum, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `split` the `data.frame` to `list` by the 'name' column, `cbind` the `list` elements.  We can change the column names using `sub` or `paste`.

```
res <- do.call(cbind,split(df[-1], df$name))
colnames(res) <- sub('([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)', '\\2_\\1', colnames(res))
res
#  MeasA_A MeasB_A MeasA_B MeasB_B
#1       1       7       4      10
#2       2       8       5      11
#3       3       9       6      12
```

---

If we want to use `dcast`, we may need to create sequence column grouped by the 'name'.  Here, I am using `dcast` from the devel version of 'data.table' i.e. `v1.9.5` as it can take multiple `value.var` columns.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create the sequence column ('i1'), grouped by 'name', use `dcast` and specify the `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, i1:= 1:.N, by = name]
dcast(df, i1~name, value.var=c('MeasA', 'MeasB'))[, i1:= NULL][]
#   MeasA_A MeasA_B MeasB_A MeasB_B
#1:       1       4       7      10
#2:       2       5       8      11
#3:       3       6       9      12
```

In a similar way we can use the `reshape` from `base R`.  We create the sequence column using `ave` and use that as 'idvar`in`reshape`.

```
df1 <- transform(df, i1= ave(seq_along(name), name, FUN=seq_along))
reshape(df1, idvar='i1', timevar='name', direction='wide')[-1]
#  MeasA.A MeasB.A MeasA.B MeasB.B
#1       1       7       4      10
#2       2       8       5      11
#3       3       9       6      12
```

Comment: ah ha yes lovely thats the one. So to break it down, 'split' splits it by name (what is df[-1]?) and cbind brings them back together. Im not sure what 'do.call' is but I can google that one.

Comment: @Pete900 I am just removing the first column using `df[-1]` as you don't have that column in the expected output.  When you are `cbind`ing list elements, use `do.call` as the `cbind` alone will not work.