# How to count levels of a factor in a data.frame, grouped by another value of that data.frame [GNU R]

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this

```
VAR1 VAR2
1999 USA
1999 USA
1999 UK
2000 GER
2000 USA
2000 GER
2000 USA
2001 USA
```

How do I count any level of VAR2 for each year?

What I want is a plot, where the x-axe is the year, and the y-axe is the count of any level in VAR2

Comment: And check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10130579/1478381) for another simillar reshaping problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of ways and this question is undoubtedly a duplicate. What have you tried? You can use `dcast` in the `reshape2` pacakge.

```
require(reshape2)
dcast( df , Country ~ Year , length )

#  Country 1999 2000 2001
#1     GER    0    2    0
#2      UK    1    0    0
#3     USA    2    2    1
```

Comment: to plot this data with ggplot, this code works for me:
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Year),fill=Country)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")

Answer (score 3):

The data.table solution

```
library(data.table)

new.dat = data.table(dat)[,length(unique(var2)),by=var1]
new.dat=as.matrix(new.dat)
plot(x=new.dat[,1],y=new.dat[,2])
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of:

let dat = your data frame

```
with(dat,table(VAR1,VAR2))
```

The output will look something like this:

```
      VAR2
VAR1   GER UK USA
  1999   0  1   2
  2000   2  0   2
  2001   0  0   1
```

Hope this helps.